# TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled in TransactionScope not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, transactionscope

I have a scenario where I am enabling transactions on ASP.NET web APIs.In this particular case, my web API uses multiple dbcontexts (since we are dealing with multiple databases).For this, I am creating a new action filter.

To be precise in a web API project I start a transaction scope in 'OnActionExecutingAsync' method and then complete the transaction scope in 'OnActionExecutedAsync' method of action filter.

What I am observing is that when I have TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled (as required by async scenario) somehow Transaction.Current becomes null in 'OnActionExecutedAsync' method. Whereas in case of TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Suppress it stays and all the database operations in the web API are wrapped in transaction as expected but when dispose of is called I get an exception that transaction scope has to be disposed on same thread ( which is correct and as per my understanding the whole point of having TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled was to cater to this scenario).

Can anybody explain why TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled is behaving in this way or if I am doing something wrong in this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Check below article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

And this one

> As we can see outside the using block the Transaction.Current property is null. Inside the using block the Transaction.Current property is not null. Even a method in the call stack like SomeMethodInTheCallStack can access Transaction.Current as long as it is wrapped in the using block.

https://particular.net/blog/transactionscope-and-async-await-be-one-with-the-flow